# ImportError: cannot import name 'EthJsonRpc'

Tags: python, python-3.x

ethjsonrpc is already installed and i'm using python 3.6.4.

but can't import ethjsonrpc *the funniest part is it was working perfectly earlier.*

The error is

```
 from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from ethjsonrpc.client import (EthJsonRpc, ParityEthJsonRpc,
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/client.py", line 7, in <module>
>     from ethereum import utils
>   File "/home/user/python/ethereum.py", line 17, in <module>
>     from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc
> ImportError: cannot import name 'EthJsonRpc'
> ```

Comment: Have you named one of your files `ethjsonrpc.py`? Try `import ethjsonrpc; print(dir(ethjsonrpc))` and see if it contains methods that you have written rather than the actual library.

Comment: >>> import ethjsonrpc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ethjsonrpc.client import (EthJsonRpc, ParityEthJsonRpc,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ethereum import utils
  File "/home/user/python/ethereum.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc
ImportError: cannot import name 'EthJsonRpc'
>>> print(dir(ethjsonrpc)
...

Comment: Ok, so you can't even import the module

Comment: import ethjsonrpc gives same error and print(dir(ethjsonrpc)  give jsut ...

Comment: whats the other possible ways to import the module actually i used the same ethjsonrpc earlier

Comment: You can't because it's trying to import other components in `__init__` so it will always fail. You could try reinstalling the library.

Comment: so what should i do   uninstall the current ethjsonrpc  and reinstall it ?

Comment: Yes, try that. I'm not sure what else you can do.

Comment: Hmmm: https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc#important-note that's not particularly helpful

Comment: yeah i have reinstalled the module but error still remains

Comment: Looks to me like the package is broken. There's a cyclic import between `jsonrpc` and `ethereum`. Maybe try upgrading the `ethereum` module.